# Can you help me to improve this?

Tags: c, performance, if-statement

I want to improve this part of a code, I was thinking about using for:

```
        if((0 < NumberOfSensor) && (NumberOfSensor< 9))MaxPageNumber = 1;
        if((8 < NumberOfSensor) && (NumberOfSensor< 17))MaxPageNumber = 2;
        if((16 < NumberOfSensor) && (NumberOfSensor< 25))MaxPageNumber = 3;
        if((24 < NumberOfSensor) && (NumberOfSensor< 33))MaxPageNumber = 4;
        if((32 < NumberOfSensor) && (NumberOfSensor< 41))MaxPageNumber = 5;
        if((40 < NumberOfSensor) && (NumberOfSensor< 49))MaxPageNumber = 6;
        if((48 < NumberOfSensor) && (NumberOfSensor< 57))MaxPageNumber = 7;
        if((56 < NumberOfSensor) && (NumberOfSensor< 65))MaxPageNumber = 8;
```

Comment: All of your integer interval checks are the same "width" so you can replace that whole thing with `if (0 < NumberOfSensor && NumberOfSensor < 65) MaxPageNumber = ((NumberOfSensor + 7) / 8);`

Comment: If (NumberOfSensor == 2), MaxPageNumber will be equal to 9/8. Does the program make it 1? I am still learning so my question may seem very simple.

Comment: If my assumption is correct that `MaxPageNumber` and `NumberofSensor` are all integer, then 9/8 will become 1 when assigned to `MaxPageNumber`. You didn't say they were declared as integer, but I assume they are based upon context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't indicate the data types of your variables, but based upon the context, I'll assume they are of an integer type. Since all of your integer interval checks are the same "width" you can replace the multiple range checks with a calculation and one conditional:

```
if (NumberOfSensor > 0 && NumberOfSensor < 65)
    MaxPageNumber = (NumberOfSensor + 7) / 8;
```

Again, this assumes the variables are of integer type. In C, when dealing strictly with integer arithmetic and assignment, integer division takes the *floor* of the result, so for example, 9/8 results in 1.

Your code doesn't change `MaxPageNumber` if `NumberOfSensor` is <= 0, or > 64. Thus, the `if` conditional is still needed if you want the code to behave exactly the same way as the original.

Note that the above calculation has the same result as the calculation posted in the other answer. Either one will do.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `NumberOfSensor` is an integer from 1 to 64. If that's the case then you can simply use:

```
MaxPageNumber = ((NumberOfSensor-1) / 8) + 1;
```